# Azure DevOps - npm install failure and downgrade python version

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, node-java

I am a newbie to Azure and developing an nodejs application that interacts with some java class. I'm using `node-java` module to implement it. Everything worked well in the local but when I try to deploy my changes on Azure, the pipeline has an exception while executing `npm install`.

**Problem**
The error happens while executing `node-gyp rebuild` so, the postInstall for `node-java` is failing.

**Solution**
I've got the solution that I need to downgrade the python version to 2.x.

**Question**
I'm not sure how to downgrade the package on Azure DevOps?

I've attached a screenshot for your reference,

[image]

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Which build image are you using?  Python 2.7.14 is [installed](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2017-Server2016-Readme.md#python-64-bit) on the VS2017 image.

Comment: I believe it's 3.6,  `gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\python.EXE -c import sys; print`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it!

I need to edit my existing build pipeline and add a task with python 2.x version.

Pipeline -> Edit -> Plus Icon on Agent Job -> Select Python Version -> Use 2.x.